# How to use laravel custom model functions?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two Models with relationship for video categories and videos

> ***VideoCats*** 
>  id | name
>
> ***Videos*** 
>  id | name | cat_id

I want to create a function in Model that would display number of videos according to the categories existing in the VideoCat table.

This is my Model **VideoCat.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VideoCat extends Model
{
    public function video()
    {
        return($this->hasMany('App\Video'));
    }

    public function lastfour($id)
    {
        self::with('videos')->where('name', $id)->take(5)->get();
    }    
}
```

and this the View where I want to display videos according to their categories

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12" style="position: relative">
    @foreach ($cats as $cat)
    <div>
      <h5>{{$cat->name}}</h5>
    </div>
    <div style="position: relative;margin-bottom: 20px;">
      @foreach ($cat->videos) as $video)
      <div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: black; opacity: .5; top: 0; left:0"> 
      </div>

      <a href="/bandvideos/{{ $video->id}}">
        <img width="100%; margin-top: 15px; border-radius: 6px;"  
             src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/{{ $video->youtube_id}}/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="">
        <img src="/photos/play.png" 
             style="position:absolute; top:36%; left:42%; height:30%; width:18%" alt="" />
      </a> 
      @endforeach
    </div>
    @endforeach
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the error? Sorry but I cannot understand what is the question.

Comment: during create relationship function you are using `video` but when are you calling or using `videos`  as relation. Although, your question is not much clear to me, but as far I understood, may be you should use `video` instead of `videos`. Or rename your `video` function to `videos` in your model.

Comment: Make more sense to me also: renaming the function to `videos()`

Answer (score 1):

Your models aren't very clear, but is this is correct: (`VideoCat` has many `Video`), then this should do the trick:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class VideoCat extends Model
{
    public function videos()
    {  //           ^^^^^^ [1]
        return $this->hasMany('App\Video', 'cat_id');
    }  //                                  ^^^^^^^^ Specifying the foreign key. [2]

    public function lastfour($id)
    {
        self::with('videos')->where('name', $id)->take(5)->get();
    }

}
```

### Notes

1 - You have a one-to-many relationship, so it makes more sense to rename the relationship from `video` to `videos` (a `VideoCat` has many `Video`s)

2 - Given that your parent model is called `VideoCat`, Laravel will look up for a field named `video_cat_id` in your `videos` table instead of the `cat_id` that you want to use. In order to address this, you need to specify a custom foreign key when declaring the relationship. Check [this section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) of the documentation.